# What do the names means in settings > application manager > current app?

Tags: applications, storage

In `settings`>`application manager`>`<your app>` we got some infos about her.

What do they means? I am quite confused.
I really need to know it but somehow its quite hard to guess. Where can I get that full descibed information about this stats?

The most important things to know (first):

- Total
- Application
- Data

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Total = Application + Data

Application = Size of APK file of the app

Data = Space consumed by `/data/data/<Package_Name_of_App>` (it contains data stored by the app)

---

Other stats details:

- If `Force Stop` button is active, it means the app is running in background. You can use this button to stop the app from running.
- `Cache` section shows how much data the app has stored in `/cache` partition.
- If `Clear Defaults` button is active, it means the app is set as default to complete an action like sending email, open URL etc. You can tap this button to clear default(s).
- On the same page, you can get list & small description about `Permissions` the app has. If you need explanation of Permissions, check [this article](http://techpp.com/2010/07/30/android-apps-permissions-secure-private-data/) out.